# How to score new data after creating fastai model on tabular data?

Tags: pytorch, tabular, fast-ai

Creating a learner with

```
learn.fit_one_cycle(5)
```

and i can check the prediction from below code on test set

```
preds_test, _ = learn.get_preds(ds_type=DatasetType.Test)
pred_test_prob, pred_test_class = preds_test.max(1)
```

How to check prediction on a new dataset which is not a databunch? I am trying below

```
validateObj = TabularList.from_df(validate, cat_names=cat_names, cont_names=cont_names, procs=procs)

preds, _ = learn.get_preds(validateObj)
pred_prob, pred_class = preds.max(1)
```

but its giving me an array of `108000` compare to `45000` validation set.

is there a simple way to score new data using above learner?